# make combinations faster in python

Tags: dictionary, matrix, combinations

I'd like to produce different combinations with size from 3 to N-2 of a matrix with N*N size. The process takes a long time for matrices with more than 10 sizes. Please guide me on how to produce combinations faster for a matrix of size 50*50.
The code for more illustration is as follows.

```py
def ProduceAllPossibleCombinationsDictionary(CurrentNetworkMatrix, number_of_combinations):
    # find all possible combinations
    num_combination=number_of_combinations
    test_list= CurrentNetworkMatrix.columns

    for j in range(len(list(combinations(test_list, num_combination)))):
        controllability_combination_mean ={}

        key=list(combinations(test_list, num_combination))[j]
        Mat=CurrentNetworkMatrix.loc[key,key]
        #produce symmetric connectivity matrix
        Adj=np.triu(Mat, k=1)
        adj=Adj+Adj.transpose()
        netss=pd.DataFrame(adj, columns=Mat.columns, index=Mat.columns)
        # sum of connections between nodes of network
        m=np.sum(netss)
        a=np.mean(netss)
        dd11= pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['mean']),
                        pd.DataFrame(m, columns=['sum'])],
                       join = 'outer', axis = 1)
        for i in range(num_combination):
    #     # append all possible cases:
            c_combination_mean[key[i]]=(key, dd11.iloc[i,0])
        test.append(c_combination_mean)

    AllPossibleCombinationsDictionary=test
    return AllPossibleCombinationsDictionary
```

I have tried matrices with small size and it was ok, but for matrices of large size such as 50*50 it takes more than 3 days and no result is being showed.

Comment: Have you been able to identify the bottleneck in your code? ... there are a few functions there `np.triu(` , `Adj.transpose(`, `pd.DataFrame(` ... to improve perfomance you need to identify what is slowing you down, is there a function that significantly slower than then rest?  ... A workaround solution could also be easier; How about physical resources, will a machine with more memory or better CPU be better for this

Comment: You have `m=np.sum(netss)      a=np.mean(netss)` each of those functions will have to loop to get the sum and the mean, you can create your own function that does both in one loop